# formula to count unique values, with range and criterion?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

does anyone you know the formula to count unique values, with range and criterion?

this is the formula that I know to count unique values `=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(range,criterion)` but I need also a 1 more range and criterion, the purpose of it is for the date, but I don't know how to add it in this formula or maybe there's a different formula I need to use.

Comment: Post your sample data then show your desired output. Also mention your excel version.

Answer (score 1):

To add a criteria try-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$8=D3)*(1/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,$A$2:$A$8,$B$2:$B$8,$B$2:$B$8)))
```

For ***Excel-365*** try-

```
=ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8=D3)))
```

[image]